# Can't get value of span attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the value of a span attribute in a div. That div is part of a LI attribute. The li attributes are created with javascript (for full code, beneath). This is the html I have:

```
<ul name="products">
<li class="product" name="product2">
<input type="hidden" name="p2" value="Boter_250g/3/9.00">
<div class="product-image"></div>
<div class="product-details">
<a style="color: black;">Boter 250g</a>
<span class="price">€ 9.00</span>
<div class="quantity">
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Things I tried**

```
        productTotPrice = Number($(this).find('.price').text().replace('€', ''));
```

or

```
Number($(this).find('.product-details').text().replace('€', ''))
```

that always give "0"

js:

```
function addProduct() {
        var product = products[type];
        var productname = product.replace(/_/g, " ");

        var productAdded = $('<li class="product" name="product' + i + '">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="p' + i + '"value="' + product + "/" + qty + "/" + price + '" />'    +
            '<div class="product-image">' +
            '<a href="image">' +
            '<img src="images/' + product + '.JPG" alt="placeholder"></a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="product-details">' +
            '<a style="color: black;">' + productname + '</a>' +
            '<span class="price">€ ' + price + '</span><br>' +
            '<div class="quantity">' +
            '<label>Aantal: ' + qty + '</label> <div class="actions">' +
            ' <a href="#0" class="delete-item" >Delete</a></div></div></div></li>');

        cartList.prepend(productAdded);

    }
```

Comment: There is an error in your code `</il>` should be `</li>`

Comment: productQuantity = Number($(this).find('.quantity').find('input').val());

Comment: @jonathandion yes, i just writted it her

Comment: can you make a fiddle? with values

Comment: Where are you calling this `productTotPrice = Number($(this).find('.price').text().replace('€', ''));
`

Comment: @AgamBanga in my delete function in javascript. When a delete button is clicked he needs to know what the value was of the product

Comment: How are you referencing the `<li>` to delete it?

Comment: @belgiums there is no delete button in your html

Comment: pass `this` in the delete function

Comment: @belgiums i have added an answer & a fiddle. Please check if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a fiddle. Please check if it works for you

```
 $('body').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var text = $(this).closest('li.product').find('span.price').text()
   console.log(text.replace('€', ''))
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g6o63eak/

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('li.product[name="product'+i+'"] .product-details span.price').html().replace('$', '')
```

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/k3ca1L9b/

update:
   get the span value based on this `on_click`ing the element

```
$('li.product').click(function(){ alert($(this).find('.product-details span.price').html().replace('€', ''))})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k3ca1L9b/1/

update: 
   with the delete function

```
 <a href="#0" class="delete-item" data-i = ' + i + '>
 $('.delete-item').click(function(){
 var i = $(this).data('i');
  var price = $('li.product[name="product'+i+'"] .product-details span.price').html().replace('$', '');
 })
```

Comment: I don't have the i value

Comment: @belgiums when exactly do you want the value ? on click or on load?

Comment: when i click on the delete button

Comment: pass the i value or the this value in the delete function.

Comment: @belgiums i have updated with the change in the delete function

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jquery why not use:

```
$(".price").text();
```

Comment: Seriously? A downvote for exactly what was asked for?

Comment: I didn't do it. There is one problem. I have more li elements so he gives them all. This helped me to the next step.

Answer (score -1):

You have some invalid assumptions here.

- li is not an attribute, it's an HTML element.
- You can use `$('yourElement').attr('<attributeValue such as id or name>');`